Merging two tables excel with no matching data
I'm trying to create a table with job numbers and week numbers that looks like this









Job1
week1


Job1
Week2


Job1
week3


Job2
week1


Job2
week2



....
how do I do it?
right now I have the job column and week number column



Job#
week#




Job1
week1


Job2
week2


Job3
week3


Job4




thank you
I tried the power query and merge two table as new using full outer
the result I got looks like this









Job1
Null


Job2
Null


Job3
Null


Null
week1


Null
week2


Null
week3




Is "Job1 week1" in a single cell or in two different cells? Consider using tables to make it clearer what your data looks like.

two different cells

I can see a tutorial here on it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/cross-join

Paste this code into the Advanced Editor.
Change the Name in the Source step to reflect your actual data table name.
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Job#", type text}, {"week#", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "weeks", each #"Changed Type"[#"week#"], type {text}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"week#"}),
    #"Expanded weeks" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Removed Columns", "weeks")
in
    #"Expanded weeks"

From your data

If you prefer a formula, and you have 365, you can use:
=LET(
    d, Table1,
    hdrs, Table1[#Headers],
    jobs, INDEX(d, INT(SEQUENCE(ROWS(d) ^ 2, , 0) / 3) + 1, 1),
    weeks, INDEX(
        d,
        MOD(SEQUENCE(ROWS(d) ^ 2, , 0), ROWS(d)) + 1,
        2
    ),
    VSTACK(hdrs, HSTACK(jobs, weeks))
)



@MarcoDong Take a look at the last step before you see that error and ensure that the column headers match exactly (including case). Without your actual data and code, hard to be sure.

@MarcoDong I have added a formula approach, and also shown the source table so you can compare the headers with what you are using in your Power Query code.

I can propose you the next more robust solution:

D1 =REDUCE(A1:B1,TOCOL(A2:A6&","&TOROW(B2:B4)),LAMBDA(a,i,VSTACK(a,TEXTSPLIT(i,","))))
D19 =REDUCE(A19:B19,TOCOL(A20:A22&","&TOROW(B20:B24)),LAMBDA(a,i,VSTACK(a,TEXTSPLIT(i,","))))

the common formula is
=REDUCE(header,TOCOL(jobs&","&TOROW(weeks)),LAMBDA(a,i,VSTACK(a,TEXTSPLIT(i,","))))


